PC crash on booting ubuntu-installer from USB
I am struggeling with a PC I got from my workplace.
The components are old (around 2009/2010):

Motherboard: Gigabyte P55A UE4(rev 2.0) up-to-date with F15
CPU:
Intel i7 875k (x64)
GPU: EVGA 01G-P3-1313-KR GeForce 210 1GB
GDDR3
RAM: 2 * 4GB DDR3 (memtest done and had 0 errors also switched them and tested it with only one)
BIOS: AWARD BIOS:

2 x 16 Mbit flash
Use of licensed AWARD BIOS
Support for DualBIOS™
PnP 1.0a, DMI 2.0, SM BIOS 2.4, ACPI 1.0b



Now when I boot from the USB using Ubuntu 20.04/22.04/24.04 or Debian created with RUFUS (or balenaEtcher, its the same result), I will get a boot screen for about 1-2 seconds with rapid text. Before the PC restarts (crashed?) the last "line" is "Freeing initrd memory: 67268K"
I tried some solutions from other posts (not exatly same problem or same system or so) but those did not work.
Strange enough: I can boot and install Win7 and Win11 without any problems
I recorded the boot with my phone (dont know else how to do without a capture card)
in Slow-Mo: https://streamable.com/qwkxq2
Thanks in advance for all helpful answers

Might have to do with Secure Boot and where the installation media was built. Did you try installing Win 10 or 11, and using that machine to make Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installation USB using the latest Rufus?

@DrMoishePippik I will try that. thats a good idea

@DrMoishePippik same result, however now I got BSOD when trying to install Win11. but thanks for the tip

@DrMoishePippik I tried it with Win7. but Win11 now worked 23h2 (24h2 did not) so will try with that again

Can you try install an older version of Ubuntu (18.04 LTS in my case) ? Please consider this option, and verify the PC you have support the OS or the architecture of the OS (64/32bits)

@FuxT tried to install 18.04, mint, arch linux but everytime its the same result. dont know if the GeForce 210 is the problem, but I cant exchange it or remove it as my board does not have a video output
